# Angular file uploading to variable

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-file-upload

I'm trying to upload image to variable using drop area and I found out ng2-file-upload but it only uploads to url. Is there any way I can trick it, or maybe some other tools I can use for this? Generally i want to upload image droping it to an area on my page and store it in models field, then save it via rest to database.  I use angular 4.

As and example i found this https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload
and demo: http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/
But I found only examples of immediately saving it with rest, instead I want to store it in my variable.

Comment: please try to post your code for understand your question clearly to others.

Comment: By looking at the source Fileuploader has an attribute named `queue`, which stores the files. Post some code related to your problem to narrow down the solution.

Comment: Or manually upload file, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45492440/2235158

Comment: i think queue storing path to files or something like this, adding some details to question post

Comment: Found an answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182190/how-to-make-simple-customized-drag-and-drop-functionality-in-angular2-with-file